# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error with stored procedure and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to insert data into Oracle database from ASP.NET MVC application. I am using a stored procedure to do so, but I get this error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too
>   small ORA-06512: at "C##AET.KATEGORIJA_PKG", line 40 ORA-06502:
>   PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

Procedure code is:

```
PROCEDURE INS_KATEGORIJA
  (
    P_NAZIV IN KATEGORIJA.NAZIV%TYPE,

    P_KATEGORIJA_ID OUT KATEGORIJA.KATEGORIJA_ID%TYPE,
    P_REZULTAT OUT NUMBER,
    P_PORUKA OUT VARCHAR2
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    P_REZULTAT := 1;

    SELECT KATEGORIJA_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO P_KATEGORIJA_ID FROM DUAL;

    INSERT INTO KATEGORIJA
    VALUES (P_KATEGORIJA_ID, P_NAZIV);

    P_REZULTAT := 0;
    P_PORUKA := 'DB: Kategorija uspesno uneta.';

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      P_REZULTAT := 1;
      P_PORUKA := 'DB: ' ||SQLCODE|| ' - ' ||SQLERRM;
  END INS_KATEGORIJA;
```

And the method calling it:

```
List<OracleParameter> izvrsiTransakciju(string nazivProcedure, List<OracleParameter> parametri, OracleTransaction transakcija)
        {
            try
            {
                using (OracleCommand komanda = new OracleCommand(nazivProcedure, konekcija))
                {
                    komanda.Transaction = transakcija;
                    komanda.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    komanda.BindByName = true;

                    List<OracleParameter> izlazniParametri = new List<OracleParameter>();

                    foreach (OracleParameter p in parametri)
                    {
                        komanda.Parameters.Add(p);

                        if (p.Direction != ParameterDirection.Input) izlazniParametri.Add(p);
                    }

                    komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    return izlazniParametri;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception("Greška pri izvršavanju transakcije: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The methods that communicates with the database are:

```
    public  List<OracleParameter> PokreniTransakciju(string nazivProcedure, List<OracleParameter> parametri)
            {
                try
                {
                    List<OracleParameter> listaParametara;
                    using (konekcija)
                    {
                        konekcija.Open();

                        using (OracleTransaction transakcija = konekcija.BeginTransaction())
                        {
                            listaParametara = izvrsiTransakciju(nazivProcedure, parametri, transakcija);

                            int rezultat = Convert.ToInt32(listaParametara.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ParameterName == "P_REZULTAT"));
                            if (rezultat != 0)
                                transakcija.Rollback();
                            else
                                transakcija.Commit();

                            return listaParametara;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }

    List<OracleParameter> izvrsiTransakciju(string nazivProcedure, List<OracleParameter> parametri, OracleTransaction transakcija)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (OracleCommand komanda = new OracleCommand(nazivProcedure, konekcija))
                    {
                        komanda.Transaction = transakcija;
                        komanda.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        komanda.BindByName = true;

                        List<OracleParameter> izlazniParametri = new List<OracleParameter>();

                        foreach (OracleParameter p in parametri)
                        {
                            komanda.Parameters.Add(p);

                            if (p.Direction != ParameterDirection.Input) izlazniParametri.Add(p);
                        }

                        komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        return izlazniParametri;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw new Exception("Greška pri izvršavanju transakcije: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }

public OracleParameter NapraviParametar(string naziv, object vrednost, OracleDbType? tip, ParameterDirection pravac)
        {
            OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter();

            param.ParameterName = naziv;
            param.Direction = pravac;

            if (tip != null)
                param.OracleDbType = (OracleDbType)tip;

            dodajVrednost(param, vrednost);

            return param;
        }

        void dodajVrednost(OracleParameter param, object vrednost)
        {
            if (vrednost == null) return;

            if (vrednost is int)
                param.Value = (int)vrednost;
            else if (vrednost is decimal)
                param.Value = (decimal)vrednost;
            else if (vrednost is string)
                param.Value = (string)vrednost;
            else if (vrednost is DateTime)
                param.Value = (DateTime)vrednost;
        }
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

**[SOLUTION]**
With much appreciated assistance from *LauDec*, I figured out that one must specify the `Size` attribute of an `OracleParameter` object when defining `Varchar2` parameters. Added that, and the problem was solved.

Comment: what is the size of your KATEGORIJA.NAZIV column ?  And what is the category name that you are passing when you call the izvrsiTransakciju function ? I suspect it is too big to fit in the NAZIV column

Comment: @LauDec this was what I thought at first, but the column type is VARCHAR2(50) and I am passing "Test1" every time.

Comment: The other possibility I see is a problem neither in your procedure nor in the code shown but in the caller of izvrsiTransakciju. The caller will define the OracleParameter passed as out variables. If it defines P_PORUKA too small, your return message will not fit in the out variable. you can try to set the value of P_PORUKA to an empty string in your procedure. If it goes through, then it's your problem

Comment: @LauDec Thank you very much. When I get home I will definitely try it and tell you if it worked :)

Comment: @LauDec This worked! I have never experienced this kind of behavior before. Do you, maybe, know how to get around it? If you write your previous comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently, it comes from variable affected to the `P_PORUKA` out parameter when calling the `INS_KATEGORIJA` procedure which is too small to store the message you are trying to put in ( based on discussion in comments ).

If you called the INS_KATEGORIJA from inside your package, I would have understood the behavious :

```
  DECLARE 
    PORUKA VARCHAR2(10); 
    KATEGORIJA_ID NUMBER; 
    REZULTA NUMBER; 
  BEGIN 
    INS_KATEGORIJA('TEST',KATEGORIJA_ID,REZULTA,PORUKA); 
  END;
```

This will definitely raise the mentionned error message. But I didn't expect when calling from the outside. ( Does your code calls directly the  `INS_KATEGORIJA` or does it call another procedure from your package which calls `INS_KATEGORIJA` ? )

I Guess you have to change the code in the caller of `PokreniTransakciju`, the one who defines the out variable(and their size) used to call the procedure

Edit : The reasons was the following based on OP's comment :

> When one defines OracleParameter of Varchar2 type,
>   OracleParameter.Size is required (it seems it is set to 0 if it isn't
>   manually set).

Comment: I don't see how the app code could interfere. P_PORUKA is defined as `string`, which can theoretically hold more than 2^31 characters. On the other hand, parameters in Oracle procedures are defined without length. I don't understand this problem :) but thanks for your answer - it is unfortunate not to be able to assign text to P_PORUKA (message parameter), as it should hold database error messages, but at least it works...

Comment: You should be able to. there is no reason why not. but without the content and type of the `parametri` variables, the code that calls the `izvrsiTransakciju` and the rest of the package, I can't check if there is another reason :(

Comment: After several days - I finally found it! The problem was my inexperience. When one defines `OracleParameter` of `Varchar2` type, `OracleParameter.Size` is required (it seems it is set to 0 if it isn't manually set). I defined a separate method that generates `Varchar2` parameters, and it works just fine now :) But I couldn't have done it if you hadn't pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: Good to hear. I will edit my answer to add your comment so that the next one will have it directly without having to go through all the comments

Comment: Thanks @dzenesiz, After 2 hours of struggling on why it is not working, setting the size solved my issue.